# I want image path through XML in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Can anybody help me, i have 4-5 images in my HTML page but I want to load it through XML. I want code for the same using Javascript or Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Could you formulate your question more precisely?

You can do an AJAX call to get your XML via [`jQuery.get(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), then do something like

```
 $(xml).find('image').each( function() { 
        $(document).append($('<img src="' + $(this).attr('source') + '">;')
  });
```

in `success` of your `get()`.
The code above assumes you have `<image source="myimage.png"/>` kind of tags in your xml... change it accordingly.